# Active Directory PrincipalContext.ValidateCredentials domain disambiguation

Tags: c#, active-directory, multiple-domains

I'm dealing with two domains - one is a trusted domain.  There may be a JohnSmith on one domain and another JohnSmith on the other.  Both of these people need to log into my application.

My problem: it doesn't matter which domain I pass in - this code returns true! **How do I know which JohnSmith is logging in?**

```
    static public bool CheckCredentials(
        string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
        {
            return context.ValidateCredentials(userName, password);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ValidateCredentials` works with `userPrincipalName` you perhaps can try to build the first parameter (username) combining the login and the domain to create the username `JohnSmith@dom1.com` versus `JohnSmith@dom2.com`.

Answer (score 4):

You can always retrieve the full DN of the user who has logged in using

```
UserPrincipal up = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName);
up.UserPrincipalName // shows user@domain.com
up.DistinguishedName // shows CN=Surname,OU=group,DC=domain,DC=com
up.SamAccountName    // shows login name
```

Use the up.SamAccountName to subsequent calls to ValidateCredentials including the domain name - you can't have 2 users who log in using the same sAMAccountName after all!

The DistinguishedName will definitely show you which JohnSmith logged in.

Answer (score 3):

Based on JPBlanc's answer, I've re-written my code.  I've also added a try/catch in case a bogus domain is passed in.

```
    static public bool CheckCredentials(
        string userName, string password, string domain)
    {
        string userPrincipalName = userName + "@" + domain + ".com";

        try
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain))
            {
                return context.ValidateCredentials(userPrincipalName, password);
            }
        }
        catch // a bogus domain causes an LDAP error
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer will fail with Domains that contain different email addresses within them. Example:

```
Domain = Company

User1 = employee@department1.com (under company Domain)

User2 = employee2@Department2.com (under company Domain)
```

The provided answer will return false using:

```
userName = "employee";
domain = "company";
string userPrincipalName = userName + "@" + domain + ".com";
```

The correct way to encompass users across domains is:

```
string userPrincipalName = userName + "@" + domain;
```

without the .com portion it searches the user AT that domain instead of searching for an email within a global domain.