# Active Directory Authentication with Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: ios, authentication, xamarin, active-directory, ldap

Is it possible to connect to a local Active Directory (not Azure Active Directory) server through a Xamarin iOS app and use it for authentication? If so, how?
I tried to use the PrincipalContext class and the "ValidateCredentials" method as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9473314/active-directory-principalcontext-validatecredentials-domain-disambiguation) but this gives me a

```
System.NotSupportedException
```

If also tried to use the DirectoryEntry() class as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813452/connect-to-active-directory-via-ldap) but this also returns

```
System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.DirectoryServices is not supported on this platform
```

Comment: Those functions are Windows platform specific as they use non-managed/Win-native libraries and thus are stubbed in Mono on other platforms. There are some iOS-based (arm and x86) OpenLDAP libraries floating around (you will need to be up to compile FAT libraries/framework to support the iOS sim and physical devices as there are no ready made libs that I currently know of), google/bing are your best choices for that. IMHO, you are way better off w/ using Microsoft Graph on the mobile client against an Azure AD that is using a local AD server as the authoritative via Azure AD Connect.